# How do I install sklearn module properly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to install `sklearn` module using `pip command` but after the installation is completed , all I can see is this folder

```
C:\Users\Aditi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\sklearn-0.0-py3.8.egg-info
```

In my directory and even the error says `module name sklearn not found`.
I've tried reinstalling it many times but still I'm not able to see the main `sklearn` folder in the above directory.Only 1 folder is installed i.e s`klearn-0.0-py3.8.egg-info` .Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please try this: pip3 install sklearn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install using command `pip install scikit-learn` or you can use `pip install sklearn` but I prefer the first one.

If it still not work for you, you can update the numpy or reinstall the numpy.

You can check [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) all the help related to installation and verifying the installation of scikit-learn